# Creating additional forms in Ushahidi Android app

Tags: php, android, forms, ushahidi

I am now currently developing a monitoring system using Ushahidi. I have a few questions about the Android application.

Is it possible for me to create multiple forms in the Android app? What I have in mind is to create forms that users can choose from in the app, and send those information filled in the form in the website.

Example:

Form A - user uses app, fill in form - send to server - store in Form A database
Form B - user uses app, fill in form - send to server - store in Form B database

any pointers on how to achieve this in Ushahidi?